# Is it acceptable to daisy NSOperation main into super?

Tags: ios, nsoperation

```
- (void)main
{
IDBAssert0(self.bestCapture.webpCandidate);
self.finished = NO;
self.executing = YES;

NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
UIImage *possiblycorrupted = [UIImage imageWithWebPData:self.bestCapture.webpCandidate];
NSTimeInterval  webpInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]-now;
NSDLog(@"it tooke %.2f sec to unpack webp", webpInterval);

self.microblinkCandidate = possiblycorrupted; // data superclass nsoperation processes

[super main];
}
```

first thing main in the base class does naturally is setting finished to no and executing to yes:

```
- (void)main
{
self.finished = NO;
self.executing = YES;
NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
start = now;

CGSize size = [self.microblinkCandidate size];
IDBAssert0(size.width && size.height);
IDBAssert0(self.microblink);
// this starts async processing
[self.microblink processImage:self.microblinkCandidate
           scanningRegion:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                 delegate:self];

while (![self isCancelled])
{
    sleep(1);
    NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    if(now - start > 5) {
        // #5677 microblink watchdog to detect hangs
        [self cancel];
        break;
    }

}
[self done];
}
```

cause it's not an abstract and will be used on its own as well.

the loop is for debug/watchdog purposes only

in the normal operation it's not tripped an operation is done
if this callback:

```
- (void)scanningViewController:       (UIViewController<PPScanningViewController>*)scanningViewController
          didOutputResults:(NSArray*)results
{
if([results count]>0) {
    NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSDLog(@"found barcode in %.1fs", now - start);
    self.microblinkSuccessHandler();
}else{
    IDBAssert0(self.microblinkFailureHandler);
    self.microblinkFailureHandler();
}
[self done];
}
```

is invoked when "processImage:" will have finished (in a timely fashion).

the very base class is

```
@implementation IDBAsynchronousOperation

@synthesize executing = _executing;
@synthesize finished = _finished;

-(BOOL)isFinished
{
return _finished;
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
{
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
_finished = finished;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

-(BOOL)isExecuting
{
return _executing;
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
{
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
_executing = executing;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    //      self.completionBlock = ^{
    //          NSDLog(@"image barcode search has finished");
    //      };
    IDBAssert0(sizeof(_executing)<2);
}
return self;
}

-(BOOL)isAsynchronous
{
return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can (and we often do) subclass your own concrete `NSOperation` subclass.

To make the base class subclassable, you want to make sure that you only perform `self.executing = true` once. Right now, the `main` in both the base class and the subclass do it, and you'll therefore be doing it twice. The typical solution is to pull it out of both of those `main` implementations and do it in `start` of the base class. Apple suggests that you do this stuff in `start`, anyway.

Thus having removed the `self.finished` and `self.executing` stuff from both `main` implementations, you can then implement `start`:

```
- (void)start {
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        self.finished = YES;
        return;
    }

    self.executing = YES;

    [self main];
}
```

Note, you don't have to call `self.finished = false` when the operation is starting because that will send an unnecessary KVO.

---

An unrelated observation:

If you keep the `while` loop in the base class, I'd suggest exiting the loop if either `[self isCancelled]` or if the `processImage` delegate completion methods was called (perhaps you can update some state property to designate when that delegate method was called). Right now, if the `processImage` finishes before the timeout, it will keep the operation running for the full 5 seconds.

Personally, depending upon how `processImage` was designed, I probably be inclined excise the `while` loop entirely. You generally want to avoid any polling like this at all. I might, for example, put the `[self done]` in the appropriate delegate method and then set up a timer or `dispatch_after` for the timeout.

```
- (void)main {
    NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    start = now;

    CGSize size = [self.microblinkCandidate size];
    IDBAssert0(size.width && size.height);
    IDBAssert0(self.microblink);

    // this starts async processing

    [self.microblink processImage:self.microblinkCandidate
                   scanningRegion:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
                         delegate:self];

    // cancel upon timeout

    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        typeof(self) __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if ([strongSelf isExecuting]) {
            [strongSelf cancel];
            [strongSelf done];   // if canceling calls the delegate method that calls `done`, then you don't need this here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah, the derived class is synchronous. the base is not. updated the question showing the entire base class main

Comment: Frankly, that expanded `main` of the base class raises more questions. See my revised answer. The question is whether this base class implemented `isAsynchronous` (or `isConcurrent`) or not (and if you did, does it return `true` or `false`)?

Comment: It returns YES. And it does so because the while loop might end up in debug builds only so that if there are any unexpected (lengthy) processing I'll be alerted before this is shipped. Let me update the question further. Sec.

Comment: updated the question with the pieces you deemed relevant

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: In retrospect: I've killed the daisy BTW and made the webp unpack & pdf417 verification using 3rd party (microblink API) two separate operations. Thusly, the answer to the original question is NO. But I needed your code (loop elimination , etc) anyway.